# Help on 1-regular graphs!

Tags: graph-theory

I have this for my homework. Given a graph, I can remove any number of edges in order to form a 1-regular graph or state that it's impossible. I tried some different approaches but I can't cover all cases. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!
P.S. I need to write a program for this in C++, but any mathematical lemma or whatever could be useful for this.

**EDIT**
What is the best algorithm to find the perfect matching of the graph? I ask because I looked around for it and couldn't find any pseudo-code or anything, by which I was surprised.
P.S. I read about matching and understood the hint. I "simply" need to check whether a graph has a perfect-matching or not. But how? Thanks.

Comment: What different approaches did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: A 1-regular subgraph of a graph $G$ is the same as a perfect matching for $G$. Do you know an algorithm for finding a perfect matching?